# Plugin Compatibility & Archived Builds

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

I would like to use the IntelliJ [Lombok Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317) in my IntelliJ. The plugin page shows that Lombok plugin version `0.9.16.4` is compatible with build `138`.

Firstly, it's completely unclear what the major / minor version of IntelliJ the build `138` is referring to.

According to the [IntelliJ download page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) it shows the latest build of 14.1 as "14.1.4 Build: `141.1532.4`". Huh? The build number is denoted in a significantly different format to that on the repository page.

If I download the latest build (`141.1532.4`) and attempt to install the Lombok plugin from the repository, IntelliJ informs me that it is not compatible with build `141`.

I have two questions:

- How can I find the the build number of IntelliJ from the downloads site
- How can I download build 138, so I can use Lombok?

Answer (score 1):

The format of `141.1532.4` is such: `<major version>.<minor version>.<build attemp>`, you can disregard the `build attemp`.

`138` equals to `138.*` and `138.000`. To check compatibiliy, the major version is compared first, then the minor version (if the major version is equal).

`138` is compatible with any newer/higher version than `138.000`, you probably downloaded a wrong plugin version.
You should just use the plugin manager inside the IDE.

You can look at [Build Number Ranges](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html).